# Push Notification con Vue y Capacitor

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic, ios, push-notification

Sé que no pongo código aquí pero no creo q lo nesecite. Estoy tratando de agregarle Push Notifications a una aplicación q estoy desarrollando con ionic vue y capacitor , hice uso del plugin Push Notifications de capacitor , pero mi aplicación simplemente no corre ese código o no logra registrarce en firebase , alguien alguna vez a implementado Push Notifications a una aplicación nativa hecha con vue y capacitor??